# What should be the best way to store entries that are rarely used?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm in the process of designing a database (MySQL) for a security company and wants to keep track of all security guards it hires. Due to the nature of the industry, a significant number of people are moved into a "terminated" list (mostly people who were fired on bad terms). The company wants to keep track of them since some of them have the tendency to try and re-apply to work after a year or two. Also, there are times that executives in the company think that putting a certain person in that list was unjust and they reinstate them (which is why, to my understanding, a MySQL Archive won't work)

The "center" of the database is **guards** table that has many relationships with other tables in the database, and I'm trying to decide what would be the most efficient way to design the "terminated" list. I thought of two options:

1. Have the **guards** table be in a one-to-one relationship with a **terminatedGuards** table. The problem I see in this solution is that any time I want to query the data I would always need to add a clause in my SELECT statement to exclude people that are in the **terminatedGuards** table.
2. Make a separate table with columns similar to the **guards** table, and any time a guard is moved to that table I completely erase their entry from **guards** table and just copy it to **terminatedGuards** table. The problem I see with this approach is that I would need to follow a lot of relationships that are associated with that entry (and sometime I would want to re-create them with the copied entry in the **terminatedGuards** list for reference. For example, I would need to re-link a table that holds work history of guards in different sites managed by the company with the **terminatedGuards** table, so I could preserve the work history of that guard, even if he or she was fired).

Which approach should be more efficient?

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL (LIST) Partitioning?? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html.. creating two tables that have the same structure is an anti SQL pattern.. and you need more application code to support seperate tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt you're going to have a million records in this table. Flag them by status, add an index on that status flag, and you should be fine.

Moving records between tables is always trouble, so it's usually done as a last resort. For example, if you had a billion records in the table you'd want to partition it or shard it in some capacity, but what you're talking about here is trivial amounts of data in comparison. It's unlikely you'll ever have more than a million records in this table, and if you do, obviously you're involved in a project that's of such a massive scale you can afford the hardware to host a database of that size.

Usually you'd architect this to have a `guards` table, and then some kind of associated records that define when they were hired, fired, or any other event that impacted their employment.